# How can I add item to many-to-many relationed table with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

I need help with a many-to-many problem with typeorm, typegraphql. I tried many ways to add items to the M-T-M relation table but couldn't do it. I followed TypeORM documentation but I think I am missing something.

When I try to get Teachers from Faculty it returns undefined. What type should it be? I thought it is an array and I can easily push an item to it, or spread what was the old value and add an item. However, none of the above-mentioned methods are worked.

```
 @ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Faculty extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [Department])
  @OneToMany(() => Department, (department) => department.faculty)
  departments: Department[];

  @Field(() => [Teacher], { nullable: true })
  @ManyToMany(() => Teacher)
  @JoinTable()
  teachers: Teacher[];

  @BeforeInsert()
  setId() {
    this.id = uuid();
  }
}



@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Teacher extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [Faculty])
  @ManyToMany(() => Faculty, (faculty) => faculty.teachers)
  faculties: Faculty[];

  @BeforeInsert()
  setId() {
    this.id = uuid();
  }
}



 @Mutation(() => Teacher)
  async addTeacherToFaculty(
    @Arg('teacherId') teacher_id: string,
    @Arg('facultyId') faculty_id: string
  ): Promise<Teacher> {
    const teacher = await Teacher.findOne({ where: { id: teacher_id } });

    let faculty = await Faculty.findOne({ where: { id: faculty_id } });

    if (!teacher) {
      throw new Error('Invalid credentials, please provide correct teacher ID');
    }

    if (!faculty) {
      throw new Error('Invalid credentials, please provide correct faculty ID');
    }

    const { teachers } = faculty;

    if (teachers && teachers.length == 0) {
      faculty.teachers = [teacher];
    } else {
      faculty.teachers?.push(teacher);
    }

    console.log(faculty.teachers);

    await faculty.save();

    return teacher;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiet way to go about managing a Many to many relationship is to create your own own custom join table. So Teacher will have a one to many relationship with the custom join table (lets call the join table TeacherFaculty) and Faculty will also have a one to many relationship with TeacherFaculty. TeacherFaculty will in turn have a many to one relationship with with Teacher and with Faculty. Then you can define columns for their ids that will be referenced as their join columns. For example

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Faculty extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [Department])
  @OneToMany(() => Department, (department) => department.faculty)
  departments: Department[];

  @OneToMany(() => TeacherFaculty, (tf) => tf.faculty)
  teacherConn: Promise<TeacherFaculty[]>;

  @BeforeInsert()
  setId() {
    this.id = uuid();
  }
}

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Teacher extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => TeacherFaculty, (tf) => tf.teacher)
  facultyConn: Promise<TeacherFaculty[]>;

  @BeforeInsert()
  setId() {
    this.id = uuid();
  }
}


@Entity()
export class TeacherFaculty extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  teacherId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  facultyId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Teacher, (teacher) => teacher.facultyConn, {
    primary: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "teacherId" })
  teacher: Promise<Teacher>;

  @ManyToOne(() => Faculty, (faculty) => faculty.teacherConn, {
    primary: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "facultyId" })
  faculty: Promise<Faculty>;
}
```

Now adding items become as easy as:

```
@Mutation(() => Teacher)
  async addTeacherToFaculty(
    @Arg('teacherId') teacher_id: string,
    @Arg('facultyId') faculty_id: string
  ): Promise<Teacher> {
    try {
     await TeacherFaculty.create({ teacherId:teacher_id , facultyId: faculty_id}).save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)          
    }
const teacher = await Teacher.findOne({where:{id:teacher_id}, relations:["facultyConn"]})
return teacher
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wan to write `faculty.teachers.push(newTeacher)`, you need to ensure `faculty.teachers` exists first.

In your case, you do not show any relational operation in:

```
await Faculty.findOne({ where: { id: faculty_id } });
```

change it to:

```
await Faculty.findOne({ 
    where: { id: faculty_id },
    relations: ['teachers']
});
```

Then, you can push new `teacher` to the table by `faculty.teachers.push(newTeacher)`.

Comment: What if we add faculty to teacher.faculties does this still work?